# Create middleware to prevent a user manipulates the information of other users in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a problem.
I need to prevent a logged in user can edit / view etc. information of another user changing the id in the url.

For example:

The URL is something like **myapp/users/32/edit**, but to change the id, can edit the information of other users

I tried to create a middleware, but not achieve expected results.
I created the following:

L

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class UserSecutiry
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->user()->id == Auth::id()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

But **$request->user->id** returns me logged user id, so the middleware does not work and can manipulate any user information changing the id.

How I can accomplish this task. I hope your help. Greetings from Chile

Comment: how did you associate the middleware with the route?

Comment: Hi.
I have the middleware in the kernel.php file as:
 'preventauth' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserSecutiry::class,


And the controller what I have as
$this->middleware('preventauth', ['only' => ['edit']]);

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
$request->route()->id
```

Your route should look like this:

```
Route::get('/test/{id}', [
    'middleware' => \Upping\Http\Middleware\ExtendSessionMiddleware::class,
    function ($id) {
        dd('some');
    }
]);
```

Doesn't work for global middleware.

Comment: `middleware has no way to indentify, which part of url is id` are you sure? `Move that logic into controller` actually, controllers should not have logic but code injection.

Comment: Edited my answer. 
Not sure about controllers and access regulations. Was fine for me.

Comment: Nice! Now you are able to access route parameters at middlewares

Answer (score 0):

If `$request->user()->id` returns the user's ID specified via URL then your code should work.

```
URL id | Auth::id() | Condition
-------------------------------
  1    |     3      | false
  2    |     3      | false
  3    |     3      | true
  4    |     3      | false
```

If `$request->user->id` returns the logged user. Then do something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // find the user who will be edited 
    $id = $request->route('id');
    $userToEdit = \User::find($id);

    if ($userToEdit->getId() === Auth::id()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->to('/');
}
```

I assumed that your route has a placeholder for the user id,:

```
Route::get('users/{id}/edit');
```

Comment: Both Auth::id() as $ request->user->id are returning me logged user id, so the test does not work and I can edit any user. Cheers !!.

Comment: I tried the method dd($request->get('id')) of laravel and I returns null. The URL is as you wrote. Cheers !!.

Comment: @PerroPekines, apologies.  Change `$request->get('id')` by `$request->route('id')`

Comment: Thanks for you help.
Finally to get the id had to do the following: $request->route('users');

And the middleware would look like:

        $id = $request->route('users');
        if($id == Auth::id())
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

       return redirect()->to('/');

it will be OK? Cheers